# Activate the iPhone camera, light, and microphone remotely

Tags: ios, iphone

Apps such as Baby Monitor (http://www.babymonitor3g.com/) let two iOS devices connect with each other. Once connected, one device can activate the camera, light, and microphone on the other device, even if the app is backgrounded on the other device. How is this done?

Comment: I would assume it's probably done with push notifications.

Comment: Either push notifications or the receiver is running a loop that is constantly pulling data from a server that then, depending on the server's output, turns on the light, microphone, etc. It's remotely sending data to the app, the app then handles the device.

Answer (score 1):

they don't from what I have seen ;) the receiver (baby's room) is running

Comment: doesn't the OS background the app after running it for a while? Does the OS not turn off screen and activate the lock screen?

Comment: no. uiapplication has the property applicationIdleTimer that you can set to NO

Answer (score 0):

I am developer of Baby Monitor 3G and I am sure, that we don't do this :-). It is not possible to use camera on iOS, when app is in background. Same with light etc.

What our app do is that dims LCD to save battery. But it has to run on foreground on the Baby Station side.